# Ubuntu upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04 fails

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I'm trying to upgrade my ubuntu box from 20.04 to 22.04 and getting the following error.
Can anyone help me please

```
2022-09-07 12:13:11,901 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

Here is the full error log

```
2022-09-07 12:13:11,131 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-07 12:13:11,270 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-43 with 
2022-09-07 12:13:11,271 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.15.0-43
2022-09-07 12:13:11,290 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 12090
2022-09-07 12:13:11,291 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2022-09-07 12:13:11,291 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-07 12:13:11,291 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-07 12:13:11,534 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2022-09-07 12:13:11,599 DEBUG Kernel uname: '5.15.0-46-generic' 
2022-09-07 12:13:11,608 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG Removing 'gnome-cups-manager' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG Removing 'powermanagement-interface' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG Removing 'deskbar-applet' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG Removing 'nautilus-cd-burner' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-07 12:13:11,775 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2022-09-07 12:13:11,796 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-43 with 
2022-09-07 12:13:11,796 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.15.0-43
2022-09-07 12:13:11,796 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-47 with 5.15.0-46
2022-09-07 12:13:11,808 INFO installing linux metapackage: linux-generic
2022-09-07 12:13:11,808 DEBUG Installing 'linux-generic' (linux metapackage may have been accidentally uninstalled)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,825 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2022-09-07 12:13:11,901 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2022-09-07 12:13:11,914 DEBUG denylist expr 'update-manager$' matches 'update-manager'
2022-09-07 12:13:11,914 DEBUG The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it's in the removal deny list
2022-09-07 12:13:26,538 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'update-manager' is marked for removal but it is in the removal deny list.'
2022-09-07 12:13:26,576 DEBUG abort called
2022-09-07 12:13:26,578 DEBUG openCache()
2022-09-07 12:13:27,352 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-43 with 
2022-09-07 12:13:27,352 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-46 with 5.15.0-43
2022-09-07 12:13:27,409 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 23600
```

Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list file

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security restricted main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates restricted main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports restricted main
```

Comment: The error message in your debug file means that you have installed wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages that conflict with the `update-manager` package required for 22.04. Uninstall those wrong-version or non-Ubuntu packages. You likely got those packages from *sources* that are not the Ubuntu repositories. Disable or delete those sources. Then the release-upgrade will work. If you do not understand those instructions, then backup your data and clean-install 22.04.